# Parsing XML from NSString to get values

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, xml-parsing

This question is for manipulating NSString in xcode.

I have a XML text string that I get from the web that looks like this

```
<current temperature="73" day="Mon" humidity="59" windspeed="10"></current>
```

How can I get individual values from this string and put them in my NSString variables?

e.g.

```
NSString *tempStr = ??
NSString *dayStr = ??
NSString *windspeedStr = ??
```

Comment: maybe you should try implementing an XML parser that will do the job?

Comment: Use parsers like e.g. RaptureXML for properly parsing the XML. Scanners and Regular Expressions are not the weapon of choice for such task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, download and include RaptureXML within your project as described on the [RaptureXML project site](https://github.com/ZaBlanc/RaptureXML).

For parsing the single given line, use the following snippet - your input is passed as `inXmlString`;

```
//transform string into an XML DOM
RXMLElement *rootNode = [RXMLElement elementFromXMLString:inXmlString 
                                             withEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
if (rootNode == nil || ![rootNode isValid])
{
    //do something, we failed!
}
else 
{
    NSString *temperature = [rootNode attribute:@"temperature"];
    NSString *day = [rootNode attribute:@"day"];
    NSString *windspeed = [rootNode attribute:@"windspeed"];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The basic idea is to use the NSString method componentsSeparatedByString: to parse out the data you want. You'll probably need to do a bit more work to get it exactly right for your scenario.

```
NSArray* paArray1= [pstrXMLString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
temlStr= [[[paArray1 objectAtIndex:1] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1];
dayStr= [[[paArray1 objectAtIndex:2] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1];
windspeedStr= [[[paArray1 objectAtIndex:3] componentsSeparatedByString:@"="] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: This will fail as soon as the connected web-service decides to change the parameter order (even though this answer is dangerous and should not be followed, I still did not downvote it as it might do the job).

Comment: Mark your answer is valid. My XML will never change and hence your point is valid. I ranked it up.